# Dev-C++: disable helper popup

Tags: dev-c++

[image]

I created a struct `student`
any time i want to add a field to it, say `student.gpa`, im getting this popup, any ideas on how to disable that?
thanks in advance

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but the definition of your [`main` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) is wrong. You *must* provide the return type.

Comment: Also, Dev-C++ is old, outdated, unmaintained, and comes with a very old compiler that doesn't support modern C++. There are other development environments, many which are totally free to download and use.